# Shuffle a string with mysql/sql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, random

I was wondering, if there is some way to shuffle the letters of a string in mysql/sql, i.e. something like the *pseudocode*: `SELECT SHUFFLE('abcdef')`?

Couldn't find any from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html and searching for it just seems to find solutions for shuffling results, not a string.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go:

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS shuffle //

CREATE FUNCTION shuffle(
    v_chars TEXT
)
RETURNS TEXT
NOT DETERMINISTIC -- multiple RAND()'s
NO SQL
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_retval TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE u_pos    INT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE u        INT UNSIGNED;

    SET u = LENGTH(v_chars);
    WHILE u > 0
    DO
      SET u_pos = 1 + FLOOR(RAND() * u);
      SET v_retval = CONCAT(v_retval, MID(v_chars, u_pos, 1));
      SET v_chars = CONCAT(LEFT(v_chars, u_pos - 1), MID(v_chars, u_pos + 1, u));
      SET u = u - 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN v_retval;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;

SELECT shuffle('abcdef');
```

See [sqlfiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14e41/4) for the output.

Tested successfully with mariadb 10.1 (mysql 5.6 equivalent)

Comment: Uh, wow, didn't know to expect this. What I had in mind was a "clever" use of some sort of string operation / rand selects to manipulate the string. This goes beyond my understanding, but you certainly have my thanks for this effort! I'll see what other answers people come up with. Any pointer as to how I'd use a "function declaration" like this? Is it possible to run this as mysql query and then use the function?

Comment: Can I add a function like that via phpmyadmin, by executing it from the sql tab? While this looks like a great solution, I am constrained to mysql4 here, so this solution seems out of the window :/

Comment: You can run this from phpmyadmin, but unfortunately, you will need MySQL 5.0 or greater.

Comment: Is there some other configuration that is needed, or version? Got mysql 5.5.9, but I get syntax errors when I try run your sql.

Comment: See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14e41/4 . What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10. I am using a local installation of MAMP on Mac OS X

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE FUNCTION shuffle( v_chars TEXT ) RETURNS TEXT NOT DETERMINISTIC -' at line 3

Comment: it doesn't work with Arabic strings. how do I shuffle Arabic string of a field?

Answer (score 6):

Edit: this solution is for Microsoft SQL Server.

As it's not allowed to use RAND() in user defined function, we create a view to use it later in our shuffle function:

```
CREATE VIEW randomView
AS
SELECT RAND() randomResult
GO
```

The actual shuffle function is as following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION shuffle(@string NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @pos INT 
    DECLARE @char CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @shuffeld NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @random DECIMAL(18,18) 

    WHILE LEN(@string) > 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @random = randomResult FROM randomView
            SET @pos = (CONVERT(INT, @random*1000000) % LEN(@string)) + 1
            SET @char = SUBSTRING(@string, @pos, 1)
            SET @shuffeld = CONCAT(@shuffeld, @char)

            SET @string = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@string, 1, @pos-1), SUBSTRING(@string, @pos+1, LEN(@string)))
        END

    RETURN @shuffeld

END
```

Calling the function

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'abcdefghijklmnonpqrstuvwxyz0123456789!"§$%&/()='
SELECT dbo.shuffle(@string)
```

Comment: You should probably add why/in which way your answer is different and/or better than the accepted answer

Comment: The accepted awnser uses RAND() in UDF, this doesn't work in MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in standard SQL - your best bet is probably to write a user defined function